# Memory behavior of / Possible memory leak in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I am profiling my iPhone application with the 'Activity Monitor' Instrument. When I use UITableViews and scroll through them, I see the memory usage of my application go up all the time while I scroll. When I return to the previous view and the UITableViewController gets deallocated, the memory usage goes down a bit, but not to where it was previously. But the 'Leaks' instrument does not find any memory leaks, and neither does the static analyzer find some. I also ensured that there are never more than 12 UITableViewCells allocated at any time, so those are re-used properly (the Cells are also created with an appropriate `autorelease` so they will be de-allocated when unused). I'm also pretty sure that I don't have any memory leaks built into the code of the corresponding UITableViewController.

Is this normal behavior, e.g. will the application release the memory it has claimed at a later time, maybe when it is needed somewhere else?

Cheers and thanks in advance

MrMage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have NSZombieEnabled? I've seen this cause "incorrect" results in Instruments memory profiling since those instances will hang around.

Comment: Thank you very much! Removing NSZombieEnabled did the trick. Another question: When I have NSZombieEnabled set and start my app directly, e.g. not from XCode, will NSZombieEnabled still be active? I hope not so, because I have sent my app to Apple while NSZombieEnabled was set...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge zombies will still be enabled. NSZombieEnabled is an environment variable checked by the runtime, it's not an XCode thing.

Comment: I just checked myself: it won't be active. I added the following code:

    TTAlert([[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"NSZombieEnabled"]);

And it would show 'YES' when run from XCode, but '' when run from Springboard directly.

Comment: Oh, obviously. XCode sets the variable before running the executable where the phone won't. Must remember not to comment before coffee.

Comment: This answer probably just saved me days of work trying to find what was leaking that didn't show up in either the Leaks or Allocations but was showing in Activity Monitor.  I had completely forgotten I had turned on NSZombies months ago.  On the upside, it did give me the proper motivation to hunt down every single real memory leak.